# Can I disable some BackgroundRb workers during tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, backgroundrb

I have a BackgroundRb worker in charge of dispatching some emails.

How should I tell this worker not to run during tests? Does the framework include some configuration parameter or stub worker I could use?

```
MiddleMan.worker(:emails_worker).async_send_mails(:arg => {:emails => emails})
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say stub it out in your tests.

If you are using rspec (sorry what I know best) then I would:

```
Middleman.stub!(:worker)
```

in your before block and it will let you call it, and you can test that it is called like so

```
Middleman.should_receive(:worker).with(YOUR_ARGS_HERE)
```

but it will not run.

On a side note I would also say that BackgroundRb is not up to date technology and there are much better background worker solutions now. I would say look into something like delayed job.